# Main Layout visibile when showing popup

Tags: android

My app shows a small popup window with an animated GIF when i run it. The problem is that the main layout(blank) is showing for a few microseconds before disappearing and then the popup shows. I have tried using mainLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) but it does not make any difference. Is there some way i can change the behavior so that the main layout does not show at all.

This is the main activity java file :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

      @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,AnimePopupActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
      }
}
```

This is the java file that is called by the main activity :

```
public class AnimePopupActivity extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        InputStream stream = null;
        try{
            stream = getAssets().open("382.gif");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GifMovieView view = new GifMovieView(this,stream);
        view.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

        mainLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
        //mainLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        setContentView(mainLayout);

        layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        popUp = new PopupWindow(this);
        params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.addView(view,params);
        popUp.setContentView(layout);


        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                popUp.showAtLocation(mainLayout, Gravity.CENTER, 10, 10);
                popUp.update(-1,-1,240,320);    

            }
        },100);
```

Comment: From the code you provided, it seems the `MainActivity` is completely redundant and can be removed... Set `AnimePopupActivity` as your main launcher activity in your Manifest and check the result...

Comment: you are absolutely right. That worked.Thanks!